# Segmentation fault from function call in destructor

Tags: c++

Why does this code [compile](http://rextester.com/PNAPX24445) and correctly print `"Derived"`?

```
template <class Derived>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(Derived& d) : derived(d) {}
    void f() { std::cout << "Base\n"; }
    virtual ~Base() { derived.f(); }
private:
    Derived& derived;
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public:
    Derived() : Base<Derived>(*this) {}
    void f() { std::cout << "Derived\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
}
```

But either [making `Base::f` `virtual`](http://rextester.com/FLKR20814) or both `Derived::f` and `Base::f` virtual causes `"Base"` to be printed. Also, changing `Derived::f` to `virtual` gives a [`Invalid memory reference (SIGSEGV)`](http://rextester.com/JPAR54203). I would expect those two other cases to print "Derived" since I'm calling it from a `Derived` instance.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Any warnings received?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No warnings.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/EiTkoC)! Some side-effect elsewhere?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You just reproduced the behavior of the example in this question.

Comment: But there's no `Invalid memory reference (SIGSEGV).` as you're claiming for.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You didn't make `Derived::f` virtual. Read the question carefully please.

Comment: Well. it receives a runtime error then, right.

Comment: This is a bad idea. By the time you call `f()` the derived portion of the object has already been destroyed. This is a gateway to [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Then why does only making `Derived::f` virtual cause the segmentation fault? And without any virtual the code correctly prints "Derived" even though the derived portion is destroyed?

Comment: @templateboy Because of how scalar destruction works and the resulting undefined behavior caused by invoking `f()`. When you enter the destructor of `Base` it replaces the vtable pointer with one specific to `Base`. When you attempt to invoke `f()` the vtable entry does not exist or points to something else (i.e. not `Derived::f()`. When you invoke `f()` you get UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a dangling reference.

You initialize the field `Base::derived` to be a reference to the `Derived` object via the `Derived` constructor, but then you access it in the `Base` destructor after the `Derived` object has been destroyed.

Access any object after it has been destroyed (via either pointer or reference) is undefined behavior, so anything might happen.